# Can I use SQL Developer to get only differences in data from one week to another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a query weekly to get a data set. Each week the data is a bit different. Can I do something to only get the differences from one week to another?

Thank you!

Comment: can you store data in a table? if so, you can extract only the records you don't have on it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you need some assistance, add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Yes, however, the methods available depends on your data model, so more info is needed to provide suitable suggestions.